# Eloquent relations belongsToMany()

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to find all the `posts` in various `categories`.

I have the `Post` and `Category` models related by `belongsToMany()`
as follows:

**Post**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

**Category**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

In between there is the pivot table `category_post` and everything is working well with the relationships.

The problem I have is the following. When the `user` views a `post` I want to show related `posts` and for that I want to show the `posts` that belong to the same `categories` as the `post`.

If I do the following:

```
$post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
$relateds = $post->categories->first()->posts()->get();
```

I recover the posts of the first `category`, but that post has more associated `categories`. And I need all the posts.

I have tried with:

```
$post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
$relateds = $post->categories->get()->posts()->get();

$post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
$relateds = $post->categories->all()->posts()->get();
```

And several similar things, but none works.

What would be the right way to do this, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all related `posts` using the `whereHas()` eloquent method on the `Post` builder.

```
$post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();

$category_ids = $post->categories->pluck('id')->all();

$related = Post::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_ids) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $category_ids);
})->get();
```

Here, we first get the `$post`. Then we get all `category` ids for the `$post`.

Finally, we get all `posts` where it has a `category` with an `id` found in the `$category_ids` variable using the `whereHas()` builder method (followed by the`whereIn()` query method).

I hope this helps.

Comment: OMG all morning trying things. I had not done the pluck and use ($category_ids) Thanks @thisiskelvin. This work!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Great! Enjoy your day.